# Reflection Emit: How to generate getter for comparision

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, typebuilder

I have problem in generating getterMethod for HasChildren Property in following code.

Could someone help me out of it?

Code in c#

```
 public class Sample
{       
    public ObservableCollection<Sample> Children { get; set; }    
    public bool HasChildren  { get { return Children?.Count() > 0; } }          
}
```

Code which is not working is quoted here for methodbuilder.

```
                    const string assemblyName = "HasChildrenAssembly";
        const string childrenProperty = "Children";
        const string hasChildrenProperty = "HasChildren";
        const string typeName = "Sample";
        const string assemblyFileName = assemblyName + ".dll";

        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName, assemblyFileName);
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);

        Type typeOfChildren = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
        Type genericTypeOfChildren = typeOfChildren.MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);

        FieldBuilder childrenField = typeBuilder.DefineField($"_{childrenProperty}", genericTypeOfChildren, FieldAttributes.Private);
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(childrenProperty, PropertyAttributes.None, childrenField.FieldType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
        MethodBuilder getChildrenMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{propertyBuilder.Name}", getSetAttr, childrenField.FieldType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator il = getChildrenMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, childrenField);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getChildrenMethod);

        MethodBuilder setChildrenMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{propertyBuilder.Name}", getSetAttr, null, new[] { propertyBuilder.PropertyType });         
        il = setChildrenMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, childrenField);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setChildrenMethod);

        MethodInfo countMethodInfo = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "Count" && method.IsStatic && method.GetParameters().Length == 1);
        propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(hasChildrenProperty, PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(bool), Type.EmptyTypes);
        MethodBuilder getHasChildrenMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{hasChildrenProperty}", getSetAttr, propertyBuilder.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        il = getHasChildrenMethod.GetILGenerator();
        var notNullLabel = il.DefineLabel();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getChildrenMethod);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, notNullLabel);         
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        il.MarkLabel(notNullLabel);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, countMethodInfo);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Cgt);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getHasChildrenMethod);

        ConstructorBuilder constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, new Type[] { typeBuilder });
        il = constructor.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setChildrenMethod);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        var obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { null });

        var obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type, obj1);

        assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyFileName);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not try to write IL code by your own, let a high level compiler do this for you. Albeit i am not sure if this IL code sequence would run if emitted correctly, at least you missed to declare the local variable you are using and also your branching instruction is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there anything I can refer to?

Comment: Have a look at the msdn for the ILGenerator, it provides all you need, labels for correct branching and definition of local variables. For fast and easy generation of simple IL chunks i can recommend tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net .

Comment: Great!! I will try that. Thanks again

Comment: @thehennyy! I had tried but it seems not working. Can you look into the getter of HasChildren property, please.

Comment: First of all, are you sure you want to use the `System.Linq.Enumerable::Count<class Sample>(...)` extension method and not the count property the collection provides by itself `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'1<class Sample>::get_Count()`?

Comment: @thehennyy : this is the reflection.Emit tag. Of course people want to emit IL by their own in this place.

Comment: @RegisPortalez that was not what i meant. I wanted to point out that there is quite a difference in using `return Children?.Count()` versus `return Children?.Count`. Because the first one uses the linq extension method and the later one uses the property of the collection itself.

Comment: Indeed good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify generic arguments in the `Count` method.

You must specify that generic argument is a `Sample` by using [MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your also have an extra `Ldarg_0` right after the `notNullLabel`. `this` is already on stack at this point, thanks to the `dup` operation at the very beginning.

Here is a slightly modified version wich works as you expect :

```
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyBuilder ab = ad.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("toto.dll"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("toto.dll");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("toto.Sample", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);


        FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField("<Children>k__BackingField", typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(tb), FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.InitOnly);
        fb.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]), new object[0]));

        PropertyBuilder pb = tb.DefineProperty("Children", PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(tb), new Type[0]);

        MethodBuilder getter = tb.DefineMethod("get_Children", MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(tb), new Type[0]);
        getter.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]), new object[0]));
        ILGenerator ilgen = getter.GetILGenerator();
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        pb.SetGetMethod(getter);

        PropertyBuilder pbhas = tb.DefineProperty("HasChildren", PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(bool), new Type[0]);
        MethodBuilder hasgetter = tb.DefineMethod("get_HasChildren", MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(bool), new Type[0]);
        ilgen = hasgetter.GetILGenerator();
        Label notNullLabel = ilgen.DefineLabel();

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getter);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue, notNullLabel);

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        ilgen.MarkLabel(notNullLabel);


        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                                 .Where(m => m.Name == "Count" && m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
                                 .First()
                                 .MakeGenericMethod(tb);

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Cgt);

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        pbhas.SetGetMethod(hasgetter);

        tb.CreateType();
        ab.Save("toto.dll");
```

Comment: There is no need to use a unconditionally branch to the end. You can just emit a ret instruction instead. Also it could be noted that there was a superfluous ldarg.0 instruction in the original code that made trouble.

Comment: indeed. integrated your suggestions

Comment: Thank you thehennyy and Regis-portalez.